# JQuery UI Tabs not mapping to content divs correctly in different versions of IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've have a webpage which I've added JQuery UI tabs too. The HTML code is generated by a third party which I have no control over but its mostly as JQuery expects.  When the page is viewed on my machine its working correctly however the clients machine renders the tabs along the top  but all the tab contents are listed one after another under the first tab.  So it's finding the tabs but not the content Divs.  I've tried it in chrome and the tabs work correctly.

Working on : IE 8.0.6001.19393 broken on : IE 8.0.7601.17514

What's different between these 2 browser version that would affect the browser content tabs?  Upgrading the browser is not an option as it's set at corporate level.

UPDATE:
As mentioned earlier I'm having to work against set html which requires a few tweaks before the tabs can be rendered. Mainly the href on the tabs links start off incorrect are are pointing to hidden anchors i.e. href="#profile1" when they should be href="#profile_1".

I use this code to reset the urls prior to calling tabs:

```
    var i = 1;
    $('#ProfileTOC ul li a').each(function () {
        $('#profile' + i).remove();
        $(this).attr('href', '#profile_' + i);
        i++;
    });
```

Now looking through the Jquery code the only difference I've found so far is when the tabs are created it calls "islocal" which returns true on the working browser and false on the broken browser. The reason being JQuery is using full http://* urls for the working tab anchors while the broken browser is using just the #anchor url missing the http:// completely. Which makes "islocal" return false;   I think its the map function which seems to be doing different things:

```
    this.anchors = this.tabs.map(function() {
            return $( "a", this )[ 0 ];
        })
        .addClass( "ui-tabs-anchor" )
        .attr({
            role: "presentation",
            tabIndex: -1
        });
```

after this one browser has full URLs for each anchor while the other has relative.  If I remove the URL changing code the URLs are full paths again but obviously still incorrect.

I've hacked the JQuery UI code to remove the islocal check and the tabs work but I'd like to know why and possibly get it working without hacking the jQuery UI code.

Comment: It would help if you posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I've never heard of such a small revision difference in IE8 being caused by any jQuery code. Odds are it's something else.

Comment: Agree with ^ J, sometimes, Chrome can make up for poorly structured DOM elements (think like... missing a /div tag), whereas IE is poor at it.  It's probably that's what's happening here, and as a result it works in "good" browsers, and sucks in IE.  Without code samples though, we can only hypothesize.

Comment: I would post code but unfortunately the html is rendered by a third party control and I'm having to work around it. It would be several pages long.

Comment: Can't do anything without some sort of code. jQuery UI works perfectly fine in IE8 so it's something on your end.

Comment: Added extra info and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hacked the JQuery UI code to remove the islocal check.